GitHub Action-Snowflake DB connection through schemachange using python 3.8
This is the below working yaml code for GitHub action Connect snowflake through schemachange..
Example:- V1.1.1__test_sql_table_creation.sql --file need to place in dbscripts folder in GitHub main branch
name: ohfa

# Triggers the action based on branch and path. 
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'dbscripts/**'  #Github folder where you place .sql

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  schema-change-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Retrieve repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Python 3.8.x
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.1
        with:
          python-version: 3.8.x

      - name: Execute schemachange
        env:
          SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT }}
          SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME }}
          SNOWFLAKE_ROLE: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_ROLE }}
          SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE }}
          SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE }}
          SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD }}
          SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA }}
        run: |
          echo "GITHUB_WORKSPACE: $GITHUB_WORKSPACE"
          echo "step1 : Installing schemachange"
          pip install schemachange
          echo "step2 : Running schemachange"
          schemachange -f $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/dbscripts -a $SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT -u $SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME -r $SNOWFLAKE_ROLE -w $SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE -d $SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE -s $SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA -c $SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE.xxxx.CHANGE_HISTORY --create-change-history-table

--i had added the complete working code for GitHub Action code

Hi - what don’t you understand about the error message? It’s saying that the database METADATA doesn’t exist or the role you are using doesn’t have privileges on it

it is working after adding below part @end -c $SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE.xxxx.CHANGE_HISTORY --create-change-history-table
